# Change Rails session for tests with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, system-testing

I need to test a page in my Rails 5.2 app that displays the current cart if the user is not logged with Capybara system test. The app retrieves the cart by the `card_id` saved in the rails session (`session[:cart_id] = @cart.id)`

My test looks like this:

```rb
require 'application_system_test_case'

class CartUiTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  def setup
    @cart = create(:cart)
  end

  test 'show cart also if user is not logged' do
    visit edit_cart_path

    assert_text "Some text"
  end
end
```

How can I set the session in this test? I've tried the gem [rack_session_access](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access) but I'm looking for another solution that not use this gem because it conflicts with other tests.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be directly accessing the session in system tests. If you want a user that has a session that has logged out, start by logging in the user and then log them out.  That way the browser will have the cookie that corresponds to a logged out session just like a real user would.